# sudo does not require password

Tags: root

I am running a new installation of raspbian.

Whenever I type a `sudo` command I do not require a password. `sudo passwd` let's me change  the password without prompting me for anything either. I am logged in as pi but changed the user password.

After the install I did nothing else than installing gedit and doing some python scripting.

I feel this is a security flaw if I do not need a password for any of that.

Comment: It's a *feature* or lets say for Raspbian that is by design.

Comment: As is anyone that can log on the pi can be become root. What is the advantage of that feature?

Comment: I'd go with *convenience* over *security*, given the targeted audience of the Pi and the use cases. If you want security you'll have to harden it for yourself (see the linked Q&A which addresses that point).